# Вызов веб-сервиса с помощью Postman

Tags: json, postman, авторизация

Возникла проблема с задачей вызова веб-сервиса, условия такие:

```
POST https://api.mindbox.cloud/v3/operations/sync?endpointId=hh.ru&operation=get.user

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Accept: application/json 
Authorization: Mindbox secretKey="bla-bla-bla"
```

Для решения этой задачи я использовала приложение Postman, но на этапе авторизации, где у меня дан только ключ, приложение выдает ошибку 403, никак не могу ее обойти.
Пыталась с помощью cUrl, также ничего не получилось, пишет ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а ключ, используемый для запроса - зарегестрирован на hh.ru? я так понял у вас ведь сервис, который работает через api от hh.ru?

Comment: Попробуйте в значение подставить то, что находится между кавычками: `OrR5saKsira...`. Если это тоже не сработает, то читайте документацию к сервису, т.к. авторизация может быть реализована у всех по разному.